# Не могу правильно составить регулярное выражение, группировка

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения

Есть такое

```
tab-price
tab-price-1
tab-price-2

tab-about
tab-about-1
tab-about-2
```

Нужно, что бы это было в разных группах.

Понимаю, что регулярка должна выглядеть примерно так ^(tab-)([a-zA-z])-([0-9]), пробовал разные варианты, но что то так и не смог сделать. 
https://regex101.com/r/kR1CKt/1

Comment: [Пример](https://regex101.com/r/kR1CKt/4)

Answer (score 1):

```
$RESULT = array();
$STRING = '
tab-price
tab-price-1
tab-price-2

tab-about
tab-about-1
tab-about-2
';
preg_match_all('/(tab-)([a-zA-z]*)(-[0-9]*){0,1}/i', $STRING, $OUT, PREG_SET_ORDER);
if (!empty($OUT))
{
    foreach ($OUT as $value) {
        $RESULT[$value[2]][] = $value[0];
    }
}
var_dump($RESULT);
```

Answer (score 0):

Можно использовать именные захватывающие подмаски + опциональную группу для необязательной части строки:

```
^tab-(?<name>\w+)(?:-(?<id>\d+))?$
```

См. [демо онлайн](https://regex101.com/r/geEO1g/1).

**Подробности**

- `^` - начало строки
- `tab-` - буквальная подстрока
- `(?<name>\w+)` - Захватывающая подмаска "name": 1 и более цифр/букв/`_`
- `(?:-(?<id>\d+))?` - 1 или 0 повторов

  - `-` - дефис
  - `(?<id>\d+)` - Захватывающая подмаска "id": 1+ цифр
- `$` - конец строки.

[PHP-демо](https://ideone.com/9DDUVG):

```
$re = '/^tab-(?<name>\w+)(?:-(?<id>\d+))?$/';
$strs = [ 'tab-price','tab-price-1','tab-price-2','tab-about','tab-about-1','tab-about-2'];
foreach ($strs as $s) {
    echo $s . "\n";
    if (preg_match($re, $s, $matches)) {
        echo $matches["name"] . "\n";
        if (isset($matches["id"])) 
            echo $matches["id"] . "\n";
    }
    echo "---------------------\n";
}
```

Результат:

```
tab-price
price
---------------------
tab-price-1
price
1
---------------------
tab-price-2
price
2
---------------------
tab-about
about
---------------------
tab-about-1
about
1
---------------------
tab-about-2
about
2
---------------------
```